# How do you post images on the i.stack.imgur page?

Tags: support

When looking through some of the puzzles, I noticed that quite a few of them used images that they posted on the i.stack.imgur page.  When I went [on that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com), all I got was this:[image]
Is there something that I need to do to post images on this page, or is the website down?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the text editor (for either questions or answers), there's a button in the tool bar that allows you to add an image to your post:

[image]

You can either upload an image from your PC, or provide a URL to an existing web hosted image. In either case the image gets rehosted on i.stack.imgur, and the link to it is automatically inserted into your message.